# exporting graphics for ios app - support for both retinna and older devices?

Tags: export, resolution, dpi, ios

I'm making a iOS app, it needs to target newer retina devices as well as the older 3GS and iPad 1.

Usually I'd just export them at 72 PPI, but for retina is it 150 PPI or 300 PPDI (or another)?

Am I right in thinking that I just make the graphics at retina spec and the older devices will just have to use them?

Comment: What does the developer spec state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to include both resolutions. Here is a handy guide:

http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina/

http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina2/